# Fullcalendar passing options to listener

Tags: javascript, symfony, fullcalendar

I'd like to add subviews of calendar in the fullcalendar. I explain : I'd like to let a user select with checkboxes some of his items ( that would be load in ajax ) and get events only from those items but letting him to select himself and get his own events.

Thats why i need to give some informations to the listener ( as Objects that would be an array of the items id and isUser that would say if i've to load the user events )

My eventsource is from type array :

```
eventSources: [
            {
                url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_loader'),
                type: 'POST',
                // A way to add custom filters to your event listeners
                data: {
                },
                error: function() {
                   //alert('There was an error while fetching Google Calendar!');
                }
            }
        ]
```

I'm on symfony and using https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle

I think that I'll have to the function that englobe the eventsource so that I'll give the variables when a chexkbox change and I should use this variable to give it to the listener.

Comment: Anyone , i didnt see any subject about it but maybe my key words were bad, so i'm still waiting and trying by my own ;)

Comment: I found a way to pass through.